# Compiler installation which is simple

Tags: c++, windows, compilation

Is there any compiler for C++ that works under W7 and is easy to install, except VC++?

I never get these scripts and linux emulations to work, and really just want to try another compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [nuwen distribultion](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) of the GCC compiler includes the compiler and all necessary supporting tools and libraries as a single Windows installer. You don't need any Linux emulation in order to use it. A similar, slightly smaller pacakage is [TDM's MinGW build](http://tdragon.net/recentgcc/). Both of these are on GCC 4.5 (as of Aug-2010).

If you want an IDE, then [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) also comes as a complete system. This has recently (Jul-2010) been  heavily improved, and comes with the GCC 4.4.1 compiler, if you want it. You might also want to look at [CodeLite](http://codelite.org/), which is also fairly easy to install.

Answer (score 1):

[Mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) is generally easier than cygwin. It doesn't come with a port of every unix tools as cygwin does, but the resulting .exes are native (no need for cygwin.dll)

Answer (score 0):

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) includes the gcc compiler and also provides a Unix look and feel which will be the other thing you need to get scripts and linux emulations to work. (This inlcude the libraries Unix libraries will have functions that VC does not have which might be the issue that you are having)

Comment: Tried Cygwin, but had many problems. Commands couldn't be found and it didn't seem to work well with W7, or I did something wrong.
I just want it clean and simple.

Comment: OK I have only used on Vista or earlier but was just run its installer

Answer (score 0):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) for Windows comes with MingW, which I've found to be reasonably easy to use and install, and the LGPL version is priced right (free as in beer).  You don't need to use any the Qt libraries in your application.  I'm not sure which version of GCC is currenlty bundled with it.  There are no licensing restrictions for the software you develop (unless you're actually modifying and redistributing source code of the LGPL version of Qt).